# How to set Tahoma as a main font in Latex?

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I have searched alot about this. But non of them help me to resolve my issue. I am trying to set the "Tahoma" as a main font for my latex thesis template but it gives an error(**Package fontspec Error: The font "Tahoma" cannot be found.**). Even the font is installed 'C:\Windows\Fonts'. Please anyone can help me.

```
    \documentclass[a4,12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tahoma} 
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried `fc-cache -fv` in the command line?

Comment: @Works on mine, use `Tahoma.ttf`  and try again

Comment: I tried so many times Tahoma.ttf but it not works

Comment: Off-topic: You should use `ngerman` rather than `german` as the option for `babel` -- unless, of course, you choose to adhere to the pre-1996 German-language spelling and grammar rules. And you probably want `a4paper` rather than `a4` as the document class option.

Comment: Please help me what should I do now?

Comment: Are you using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Do you have MS Office installed on your system?

Comment: I am using XeLaTex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150579/discussion-between-samia-rani-and-mico).

Comment: @SamiaRani  see chat. Managed to replicate your error and provided a solution

Comment: Is the name of the font "Tahoma" or "MS Tahoma" or "Tahoma-PSMT" or something else?

Comment: The font name is "Tahoma" only.